# Will_Paginate and order clause not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm calling a pretty simple function, and can't seem to figure out whats going on. (I'm using rails 3.0.3 and the master branch of 'will_paginate' gem).  I have the following code:

```
  results = Article.search(params) # returns an array of articles
  @search_results = results.paginate :page => params[:page],  :per_page=>8, :order => order_clause
```

No matter what I make the order_clause (for example 'article_title desc' and 'article_title asc'), the results are always the same in the same order. So when I check using something like `@search_results[0]`, the element is always the same.  In my view, they are obviously always the same as well.   Am I totally missing something?

I'm sure its something silly, but I've been banging my head against the wall all night.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Edited to Add: The search clause does the following:

```
def self.search(params)
    full_text_search(params[:query].to_s).
    category_search(params[:article_category].blank? ? '' : params[:article_category][:name]).
    payout_search(params[:payout_direction], params[:payout_value]).
    length_search(params[:length_direction], params[:length_value]).
    pending.
    distinct.
    all
  end
```

where each of these guys is a searchlogic based function like this:

```
#scopes
scope :text_search, lambda {|query|
    {
      :joins => "INNER JOIN users ON users.id IN (articles.writer_id, articles.buyer_id)",
      :conditions => ["(articles.article_title LIKE :query) OR
                       (articles.description LIKE :query) OR
                       (users.first_name LIKE :query) OR
                       (users.last_name LIKE :query)", { :query => "%#{query}%" }]
    }
  }
  scope :distinct, :select => "distinct articles.*"
#methods

    def self.payout_search(dir, val)
        return no_op if val.blank?
        send("payment_amount_#{dir.gsub(/\s+/,'').underscore}", val)
      end

      def self.length_search(dir, val)
        return no_op if val.blank?
        send("min_words_#{dir.gsub(/\s+/,'').underscore}", val)
      end
```

Thanks.

Comment: I created a little test case myself and everything worked fine with paginate. Do you have a scope in your model which could perhaps be overriding your order clause? The only other thing I notice is your naming of 'article_title' for the model 'article', perhaps you mean to sort by 'title'? Otherwise, have you tried ordering by 'created_at desc' and 'created_at'?

Comment: Edited to add more about the search call.  AllDayer-  I think there may be something going on there as well, but not sure what.  When I run just a normal search it works fine.  How might the article scopes override if I dont call them in the order statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the example from the will_paginate github page you can spot one important difference between their use of the :order clause and yours:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

This calls paginate on the Post object (with no objects being selected yet - *no SQL has been executed* before paginate comes along). This is different in your example: as you state in the first line of code "returns *an array* of articles". The simplest I can come up with showing the problem is

```
  results = Model.limit(5).all
  @results = results.paginate :order => :doesnt_matter_anymore
```

won't sort, but this will:

```
  results = Model.limit(5)
  @results = results.paginate :order => :matters
```

It should suffice to take the `all` out of the search method. It makes ActiveRecord actually perform the SQL query when calling this method. Will_paginate will do that for you when you call `paginate` (if you let it...). Check out the section on Lazy Loading in this post about [Active Record Query Interface 3.0](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)